# C++ Circular Inheritance and Class

Tags: c++

I'm getting the error "circular inheritance problem encountered in 'atan'" on the last line. I'm confused since it only occurs in that line and not in main(). I only include  in the cpp file and not anywhere else. Since the error is only in the class function I guess I'm doing something wrong with the class, but can't figure out what it is.

*I only threw in the main as an example of when it works. Doesn't actually serve a purpose.

//.h file

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_H_
#define CIRCLE_H_


    class Circle {
    public:
        Circle(int minVertex=12);
        ~Circle();
    private:
        int pixels;
    };

#endif /* CIRCLE_H_ */
```

// cpp file

```
#include <circles.h>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    double pi = abs(9);
}


Circle::Circle(int minVertex = 12) {
    pixels = 1150;
    double pi = atan(0) *2; // problem here
}
```

Comment: Also, I'd like to add that this is a great site with a good community. Helped me a lot in the past so far. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Circle: Circle
```

You have a class that inherits from itself, how could that work?

Comment: Hey changed that, althought the cmath function still isn't working. Any other wierd problems?

Answer (score 2):

```
class Circle: Circle {
```

Are you trying to inherit `Circle` from `Circle`?

Try simply

```
class Circle {
```

Comment: thanks! sorry for the bad question. Think I need to read up on C++ a bit more.